# Mysql : should i put my data into 1 table or split per user?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, normalization

This data is for a holiday cottage's simple accommodation calendars.
The data is simple and stores dates when each cottage is booked.

The cols would be `cottage_id, booked_from_date, booked_until_date` and I would expect around 60 rows per user per year * 200-300 users.

I should put this is one table right?

Comment: Not sure I'm reading the question correctly.  So each user books a cottage(s) 60 times a year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### COTTAGE

cottage_id,

address?,

other info...

### USER

user_id,

name,

other info...

### COTTAGE_RESERVATION

cottage_id,

user_id,

from_date,

to_date

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, this should be placed in a single table (for all cottages).

You will run into a whole world of hurt when you start placing data that should be in a single table (that can be seperated by a defining type/id) into seperate tables.

**Just think of how you are to write a query to retrieve availability accross all units, for a given date, accross 10-40 or more units?**

*Normalizing the table into a MANY to MANY structure is perfectly normal, seperating Cottages from Users and linked by a table CottageUsers with the booked dates.*

Answer (score 0):

I think Randy's answer is good...  another idea to add to his would be to use a calendar table like:

**COTTAGE_CALENDAR**

- cottage_id
- date
- reservation_id

Add a single row for each day of booking and make the cottage_id and date fields a combined primary key....then you'll prevent overbooking... (adding the reservation_id to the **COTTAGE_RESERVATION** table that Randy built, for the relational data link)....